# Programming third-party app to submit invoices to QuickBooks software

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

My client is wanting to be able to submit invoices automatically into the QuickBooks software from another piece of software that I'm writing (using Qt++/C++). It's my understanding that this can be possible with the QuickBooks SDK for C++. Can anyone definitively confirm if this is true before we move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can communicate with QuickBooks using C++.

Download the QuickBooks SDK - there are code examples in there.